# scrlayer-scrpage modifying more than just header/footer

Tags: koma-script, scrlayer-scrpage, minutes

**PS**: It was a bug in the `minutes` package. See below.

**PPS**: The author of KOMA-Script, Markus Kohm, used the opportunity to patch KOMA-Script. Beginning with 3.38.3945 this is no longer an issue.

I am experiencing a weird issue with KOMA's `scrlayer-scrpage` in combination with the [minutes package](https://ctan.org/pkg/minutes) (for note-taking in meetings).
Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

%\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
%   \lohead*{Left Head}\cohead*{Center Head}\rohead*{Right Head}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{minutes}

\begin{document}
\begin{Minutes}{Minutes of the Meeting}

\participant{Nomen Nescio, Some Body Else}
\maketitle

\topic{First Order of Business}
Lorem Ipsum Dolor sit Amet.

\end{Minutes}
\end{document}
```

When I remove the comments and add `scrlayer-scrpage` to the document, it not only modifies the header as expected, but also adds `Minutes I.` above the actual title (as shown below).[image]

As you can see, the actual header part works as expected. This only happens with `scrlayer-scrpage`! Why is that, and more importantly how can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got an answer on [another forum](https://golatex.de/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=24576): This is a confirmed bug in the `minutes` package. It assumes that `\part` doesn't create a number when `secnumdepth = -1`, but that doesn't always have to be the case. Using `-\maxdimen` would already be an improvement:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
    \lohead*{Left Head}\cohead*{Center Head}\rohead*{Right Head}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{minutes}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\min@maketitleList}{-1}{-\maxdimen}{}{\undefined}
\xpatchcmd{\min@maketitleTable}{-1}{-\maxdimen}{}{\undefined}
\xpatchcmd{\min@maketitle}{-1}{-\maxdimen}{}{\undefined}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{Minutes}{Minutes of the Meeting}

\participant{Nomen Nescio, Some Body Else}
\maketitle

\topic{First Order of Business}
Lorem Ipsum Dolor sit Amet.

\end{Minutes}
\end{document}
```

Better still would be to use `\addpart` instead of `\part` with KOMA-Script:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
    \lohead*{Left Head}\cohead*{Center Head}\rohead*{Right Head}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{minutes}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\min@maketitleList}{\part}{\addpart}{}{\undefined}
\xpatchcmd{\min@maketitleTable}{\part}{\addpart}{}{\undefined}
\xpatchcmd{\min@maketitle}{\part}{\addpart}{}{\undefined}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{Minutes}{Minutes of the Meeting}

\participant{Nomen Nescio, Some Body Else}
\maketitle

\topic{First Order of Business}
Lorem Ipsum Dolor sit Amet.

\end{Minutes}
\end{document}
```

Comment: while I agree that minutes can do it better, there is imho also a problem in scrartcl/scrlayer. Simply loading the second shouldn't change `\partnumdepth` (and the KOMA author seems to agree as one can see in the following up message in the other forum).

Comment: Yes, I've seen the follow-up. Markus seems to consider it a bug after all and will publish a fixed version.

Comment: A new version of KOMA-Script has been published (not on CTAN yet). Beginning with 3.38.3945 this is no longer an issue.