# LaTeX TOC has a first ghost line - \maketitle the culprit?

Tags: table-of-contents, titles, minutes

I am encountering a problem with the \tableofcontents, it has a blank line with a number 1 in it. I do not want it to be there.
When I delete the \maketitle, the ghost line is gone, but I need the \maketitle obviously.

What is the reason or workaround?

Thanks,
flexi

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ListTitle]{minutes}

\begin{document}
\begin{Minutes}{Titel} %Titel

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\topic{TOP 1}

\end{Minutes}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can it be that you are using an older version of KOMA-Script. See question https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/651326/16550.

Comment: Thanks, I read in the log that my KOMA version is v3.41. If I understood correctly, that shouldn't be an issue anymore.

Comment: This also happens with `article` instead of `scrartcl`. It is caused by `minutes`. So it seems to be either a bug or feature of `minutes`. BTW: IMHO the `\tableofcontents` should be outside the `Minutes` environment, but this is independent from the problem.

Comment: @Mensch The issue is unrelated to KOMA-Script. It also happens with `article`. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem also happens with standard class `article`. There is one more bug in `minutes`. To test, whether the optional argument of `Minutes` is not used, it uses:

```latex
\newenvironment{Minutes}[2][\relax]{%[short title]{Titel}
…
\ifx{#1}\relax
\def\min@titleshort{#2}
\else
\def\min@titleshort{#1}
\fi
…
```

The `\ifx{#1}\relax` test is completely wrong. For a not used optional argument it also uses the *else* code and therefore sets `\min@titleshort` to `\relax`. This results in an empty `part` entry to the ToC instead of using the mandatory title argument of `Minutes` also for the ToC entry.

Usually you should report this issue, but it seems that `minutes` is unsupported for a very long time. So best would be to not use the buggy package.

However, you can patch `\Minutes`:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ListTitle]{minutes}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\Minutes}{%
  \ifx{#1}\relax
}{%
  \ifx \relax#1\relax
}{}{\undefined}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\begin{Minutes}{Titel} %Titel

\maketitle
  
\topic{TOP 1}

\end{Minutes}

\begin{Minutes}[Short Title]{Title}
  \maketitle
  \topic{TOP 1}
\end{Minutes}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is not the best solution, but usually a hack, that seldom fails.

If you don't want the `Minutes` titles in the table of contents, you can just use something like:

```latex
\RedeclareSectionCommand[toclevel=10]{part}
```

with `scrartcl`. See the KOMA-Script manual for more information.

Comment: `\RedeclareSectionCommand[toclevel=10]{part}`

That absolutely does the trick, thank you so much! I was about to come back to say I will live with it now, but those few lines of code solved it.